# Can I use relative URL in a .properties file?

Tags: java, url

I have a java program which gets some properties from a xxx.properties file. For example the destination of a file my program works with.
How is it possible to give this file's place in the xxx.properties file with relative linking? I tried so many ways, but nothing worked. If I give the place of the file with an absolute URL it works just fine.

**Example:**

keyFileName=../res/MP00.pem <-- *does not* work.
keyFileName=/home/thomas/myprogram/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/res/MP00.pem <-- *does* work.

The xxx.properties file is in /home/thomas/myprogram/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib

I'm using an ubuntu based linux distribution, if that matters.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is un-answerable without details of how the properties file is being used.

Comment: Thank you! Next time I will give more proper details if asking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do with the fact that you load the URL from a properties file. Relative paths are always relative to some form of 'current location'. Loading the URL-String from a properties-file does not set that .properties' location as your 'current location'. Try setting the path relative to the program you run (which uses the URL-String), not the .properties-file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have thought about that too. The program which uses the URL-String is compiled into a jar file and that jar is used by a webapp. The jar file is in the same folder as the .properties (in the lib folder) so it should work but it doesn't.
Maybe the 'current location' is the webapp's current location? But which folder is that? It contains no java code, only jsps and images and metadatas.

Comment: I found out that it sets my home folder (/home/thomas) as current location. So I had to give ./myprogram/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/res/MP00.pem as relative URL. Problem is, when I deploy my webapp to a server (instead of running on localhost) I have to change the .properties file. I wanted to avoid that with the relative URL.

Comment: If you just need access to a file on the classpath, you could also go via your class' classloader: MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nameOfYourFile"); This should work to load any file residing in the classpath of your application.